# Quickly Project System-Notifications dont work ("import pynotify" fails)

Tags: python, application-development, notification, quickly

If i create a quickly-project with the following command in terminal:

```
 quickly create ubuntu-application helloworld
```

and then add in the HelloworldWindow.py the following lines,

```
import sys
import pynotify
```

the line "import pynotify" produces the following error-output on my system when i want to run the application with

```
quickly run
```

error-output:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
>     import gobject._gobject
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type`PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's `GtkCellRenderer' class size
>     from gtk import _gtk
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion`node != NULL' failed
>     from gtk import _gtk

The application won't start.

But if I want to run the following python-application

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import sys
 import pynotify

 if __name__ == "__main__":
if not pynotify.init("icon-summary-body"):
    sys.exit(1)

n = pynotify.Notification(
    "Notification",
    "Hello notify! It works!",
    "notification-message-im")
n.show()
```

e.g. by saving the code in a filename "notify.py", I am able to run the code with the command in terminal:

```
python notify.py
```

and the notification works fine!

What is the problem with the via quickly created python applicaton?? Why is the import not working?? I am new with quickly and python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into exactly the same problem.

Here's my solution.

```
from gi.repository import Notify

Notify.init ('Application')
notification = Notify.Notification.new ('Title', 'Message', 'dialog-information')
notification.show ()
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for me! (Do you additionally know how to show an individually icon from the quickly "media"-folder instead of the standard "dialog-information"-Icon?)

Comment: I'd imagine you could just point it to the file.

Comment: os.getcwd() + '/data/media/picture.png' works for me! I hope it works also after packaging. I don't understand why './data/media/picture.png' is not working.

Comment: Because the file is in the `bin` directory, probably.

Answer (score 2):

pynotify was written to work with pygtk, an older way of using GTK through Python. The new method is called gobject introspection, and has imports like:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

You can't use the old and the new system in the same application, and the quickly template uses the new system, so you can't use pynotify with it.

I have a replacement that's compatible with the new system: [notify2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/notify2). It's not in precise yet, but I've submitted a backport request for it.